# How to start image carousel on Mouse hover, and set first image when mouse out

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here I am creating an image carousel. When we hover
over the images, They will start to slide. Once we move away the
mouse, the images will be paused.

My requirement is when we move the mouse away from the carousel
it should go back to the first carousel image.
In my program, It stays at the same image where I stopped the
hover.

I am a beginner developer It would be great if anyone
can help me with it.

here's the code

codepen link: https://codepen.io/lucky_maks/pen/GdpMaP

```js
$(function(){
  var speed = 300,
      $li;
  
  $('.slider').on('init', function(slick) {
    $(slick.target).find('button').append('<span></span>');
    
    $li = $(slick.target).find('.slick-dots li');
    animateSpan(0, $li);
  });

  $('.slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: speed,
    arrows: false,
  });
  
  $('.slider').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).slick('play')
    });
    $('.slider').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).slick('pause')
    });
  
  $('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    $li.find('button span').stop(true, true);
    $li.find('button').removeClass('filled');
    
    if(currentSlide == 0) {
      $li.find('button span').css({
        'transform': 'scaleX(0)',
        'border-spacing': 0
      });
    } else {
    
      for(var i = 0; i < currentSlide; i++) {
        $li.eq(i).find('button').addClass('filled');
      }
      
      
      
      for(var i = currentSlide + 1; i < $li.length + 1; i++) {
        $li.eq(i - 1).find('button').removeClass('filled')
          .find('span').css({
        'transform': 'scaleX(0)',
        'border-spacing': 0
      });
      }
    }
    
    animateSpan(currentSlide, $li);
  });
  
  function animateSpan(currentSlide, $li) {
    var $currentBtn = $li.eq(currentSlide).find('span');
    
    $currentBtn.animate({  borderSpacing: 1 }, {
      step: function(now, fx) {
        $(this).css('transform', 'scaleX('+ now +')');  
      },
      duration: speed
    }, 'linear');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slider">
  <li class="slider__item">1</li>
  <li class="slider__item">2</li>
  <li class="slider__item">3</li>
  <li class="slider__item">4</li>
  <li class="slider__item">5</li>
  <li class="slider__item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For starters you have some undefined function calls `slick()`, did you mean `click()`? Besides that, your example code produces errors. Perhaps you could start by fixing them first.

Comment: Please check this one @vanowm : https://codepen.io/lucky_maks/pen/GdpMaP